Execute jar in docker file
I have a docker file and i want to execute jar file in that docker file but while running that docker file I am getting could not find or load main class error on GCP log I tried lot of options but got no luck:
FROM abc.com/abc-public/gcp-community-images/java-jre: 11-slim
COPY target/abc-SNAPSHOT/ /usr/app/
ENV CATALINA_OPTS="-Denv=otps"
EXPOSE 8080 8443
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/usr/app/abc-SNAPSHOT.jar"]

it is pom.xml file where i am declaring main class
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId> <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${maven.exec.plugin.version}</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<goals>
<goal>java</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
<mainClass>com.main.Main</mainClass>
<!-- <arguments> TODO: Add some real arguments to Main class here
<argument>arg1</argument>
<argument>arg2</argument>
</arguments>


Could you please explain how are you building the .jar file? Is you are using Maven you might want to declare the main class in pom.xml.

(Can you run the same jar file without Docker?)

@DavidMaze  No I can not run jar file without docker also

You need to declare the main class through the jar plugin, not the exec-maven-plugin as that is for running java code from within Maven not for generating executable jars. You are also using Spring so I would suggest to use Spring Boot which would simplify things greatly.

I can not use spring boot now, I just want to run that jar in docker file on github after building the module (batch jar module)
